# Android How to get rid of question mark at end of ellipsize

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I've defined the following TextView:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

And as expected the text is cut off if it's too long and replaced by "...". But at the end of the three points appears a question mark surrounded by a square.

How can I get rid off this question mark?

Thanks!

Comment: What text are you placing in the TextView? Sounds like a encoding error

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To quote myself from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android):

> Android's `TextView` class has the built-in ability to "ellipsize" text,
>   truncating it and adding an ellipsis if the text is longer than the available
>   space. You can use this via the `android:ellipsize` attribute, for example.
>   This works fairly well, at least for single-line text.
>
> The ellipsis that Android uses is not three periods. Rather it uses an actual
>   ellipsis character, where the three dots are contained in a single glyph.
>   Hence, any font that you use that you also use the "ellipsizing" feature will
>   need the ellipsis glyph.
>
> Beyond that, though, Android pads out the string that gets rendered on-
>   screen, such that the length (in characters) is the same before and after
>   "ellipsizing". To make this work, Android replaces one character with the
>   ellipsis, and replaces all other removed characters with the Unicode
>   character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (`U+FEFF`). This means the
>   "extra" characters after the ellipsis do not take up any visible space on
>   screen, yet they can be part of the string.
>
> However, this means any custom fonts you use for `TextView` widgets that
>   you use with `android:ellipsize` must also support this special Unicode
>   character. Not all fonts do, and you will get artifacts in the on-screen
>   representation of your shortened strings if your font lacks this character
>   (e.g., rogue X's appear at the end of the line).

Comment: Oh man, I should have read the entire book ;-) Thank you for that tip!

Comment: @GabrielWeis: Hah! I elected to do the quote, simply because it's a pain to explain, and I didn't feel like writing it up again. Assuming you have rights to fuss with your font file, somebody with a font editor (and the expertise to use one well) should be able to add this glyph.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for the explanation, but in my case I see these artifacts on a HTC Hero (2.1) but I don't on a Nexus One (2.2 or above) nor on a Samsung Galaxy S (2.2 or above). If this is a font related problem, why is that?

Comment: @Xavi: Perhaps the Hero uses a different font. Or perhaps they tinkered with the standard font and removed this glyph.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem. Somebody with FontForge knowledge fixed the U+FEFF in my custom fonts and now they work well.  Here is how he described what he did:

"I'm not good with Fontforge, so I cheated.  Basically, opened the font in Fontforge, selected the space character, ctrl+c for copy, then selected FEFF, ctrl+v for paste.  Then menu Metrics->Set Width and set to zero.  Then File->Generate Fonts."