# TextView ellipsize and broken symbols

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some problem with standard android ellipsize mechanism.

My textview xml layout is next:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/message_test_text"
        android:lines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@drawable/dialogs_text_selector"
 />
```

Then in code I'm setting Helvetica typeface to this field. And then, in the end of second line I see broken symbol after dots:

[image: Broken symbol]

Because it used in list, I see a list of squares.

Can I remove it without tons of code?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work fine with other fonts?

Comment: could be the problem wit font file.. try using a different copy of the font file..

Comment: *"Then in code I'm setting Helvetica typeface to this field"* Hopefully you have paid for a license for this font. Otherwise, please do not distribute it. *"And then, in the end of second line I see broken symbol after dots:"* This has been covered before, such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794488/android-how-to-get-rid-of-question-mark-at-end-of-ellipsize

Answer (score 6):

There is a issue [logged here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882). Many people have some or the other problem when using `TextView` with ellipsize in a `ListView`. There are many workarounds that suggest changing the textview to single line, but you cant use that.

Try setting the `android:maxLines="2"` attribute.

### Update:

Use [TextUtils.ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#ellipsize%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.text.TextPaint,%20float,%20android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt%29) API to manually ellipsize the string before setting it to the textview. See whether the ellipsized string returned by this API contains the square char at the end.

Usage sample code:

```
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
tp.setTextSize(float textSize);
tp.setTypeface(Typeface typeface);
Charsequence elipText;
elipText = TextUtils.ellipsize ( text, tp, avail, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
textview.setText(elipText);
```

Comment: i updated the answer.. ellipsize manually and see if the square char still appears..

Comment: Nice way, but next question will be "Why my textview width is 0 on first inflate?" O_o

Comment: `TextUtils` is ideal for singleline, but two lines is not so good. I found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6763689/1271424

Comment: Your answer helped me anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here I don't think it was your code. The problem is your `.tff` file which is missing the `ellipsize` character, hence the `square` is displayed. Your font was not... let's say `mobile optimized`.